# dumpbin command not listing function names in dll

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, dll, dumpbin

I have a DLL which is develeoped in VB.Net. I am trying to call its functions from my vc++ code. The dll has successfully loaded using LoadLibrary function.
But when I try calling any function within the dll, it gives a null pointer exception.

I used the dumpbin command to confirm the function arguments within my dll. But it is not listing any functions. Could it be a problem with the dll or does dumpbin support few dlls only? Please help!

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>dumpbin ECR.dll
>   Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 11.00.51106.1 Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Dump of file ECR.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
> Summary
>
> ```
>     2000 .reloc
>     4000 .rsrc
>     2000 .sdata
>    16000 .text
> ```

Comment: Try `dumpbin /exports ECR.dll` and see if you have the functions listed there.

Comment: i tried *dumpbin /exports ECR.dll* and get the same result. no functions listed.

Comment: Are any functions *exported* from that DLL?

Comment: I cannot see the dll code. Its been provided by a third party. But i am able to call the functions successfully if I load the dll in a windows project.

Comment: Most likely not. Here's [Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) a graphical tool similar to _dumpbin_. You'll probably have to provide the code that creates the dll.

Comment: I tried Dependancy walker too. There are no functions listed there either and it gives me this warning.
*Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.*

But how come it works fine for a windows app then.

Comment: A VB.NET class library project never has any exports.  Calling vb.net code from unmanaged C++ code is a non-trivial operation, that C++ code needs to load and initialize the CLR first.  And it has to do *something* to deal with the high likelihood that such code will throw an exception.  Standard techniques are making the vb.net code [ComVisible] or hosting the CLR with IMetaData.  Commonly used but a bad idea due to the very poor error reporting are writing a C++/CLI wrapper function that uses __declspec(export) and Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports library.

Comment: Thank you @Hans . I understand now. You can put that in the answer section. I will mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing before any function in your DLL file (header .h files) the name of the project with _API at the end (ECR_API).

for example, lets say we want to create a constructor and destructor for a class called Loader:

```
class Loader{
    public:
        ECR_API Loader();
        ECR_API ~Loader();
}
```

also dont forget to add export and import statements at the beggining of your header file:

```
#ifdef ECR_EXPORTS
#define ECR_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ECR __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

hope this helps!
worked fine for me.